# Source of "God could not be everywhere, so He created mothers"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, quotations

A popular line, usually attributed to the Talmud, is "God could not be everywhere at the same time, so He created mothers."  I could not find it anywhere in Jewish sources.  Besides, God is Ha-Makom -- He **IS** everywhere.

Does anybody know of a Jewish connection for that line?

Comment: I’m curious, where did you hear this attributes to the Talmud? I’ve heard it attributed as a “Jewish proverb,” or, more likely, “Rudyard Kipling,” but never the Talmud specifically.

Comment: I have seen it quoted as a yiddish proverb: "Got hot nit gekent zayn umetum, hot er beshafn mames. “God couldn’t be everywhere, so He created mothers.”  But also the Talmud -- see here  https://web.stanford.edu/group/religiouslife/cgi-bin/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/20140511_UniversityPublicWorship_sermon.pdf

Comment: This is not a quote from the Talmud. This is either a heresy or a bad joke.

Comment: Should we infer that mothers can ;)

Comment: This has received a vote to close as off-topic. While I understand where you’re coming from, the question presupposes that this is, indeed, a Talmudic quote, not just a Jewish one, and as such, I feel it should be left open.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi The Princeton link points to the story of Rivkah and to the Aishes Chayil that we recite every Friday night. I do not see how that actually deals with the quote that you are asking.

Comment: @sabbahillel  Go to the Stanford link and do a search for “God couldn’t be everywhere,” the Talmud teaches, “And so God created mothers.”

Comment: This is a [Rudyard Kipling](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/rudyard_kipling_118509) quote not a Talmud reference. The google references that I found did not give the source of the statement so that I am leaving this a comment.

Comment: Maybe define your usage of "popular". Never heard of this weird phrase